# Graph drawing libraries in android

Tags: android, graph, drawing

I want to draw a graph in my application.can any one tell me which is the best open source library used to draw a graph in android.I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**achartengine** library is very good,you can use it

**link**: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Answer (score 1):

Use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
Tried many libraries for the purpose.
Easiest to use and renders beautiful charts.
It turned out to be the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/) a try. It provides a demo application with a lot of useful code, it is open-source and free to use in any application.

Dan